# Add thousand comma separators to e_visual_map function (echarts4r package)

Tags: r, dictionary

I am making a map using the **echarts4r** package in R Studio and I am having troules with formatting the numeric values displayed in the visual map.

```
data %>%
  e_charts(region) %>%
  e_map_register("NZ", nz_json) %>%
  e_map(visitors, map = "NZ") %>%
  e_visual_map(
    visitors,
    top = "20%",
    left = "0%",
    inRange = list(color = c("#3366FF","#6699FF", "#66CCFF", "#33CCFF")),
    type = "piecewise",
    splitList = list(
      list(min = 100000),
      list(min = 40000, max = 100000),
      list(min = 5000, max = 40000),
      list(value = 0)
    #),
    )) %>%
    #formatter =  htmlwidgets::JS("
  #function(params){
   # return(echarts.format.addCommas(params.value)) }")) %>%
  e_tooltip(formatter = htmlwidgets::JS("
                         function(params){
                        return('<strong>' + params.name + 
                     '</strong><br />Total: ' +  echarts.format.addCommas(params.value)) }"))
```

I have managed to add a **comma separator** to the data format in `e_tooltip` but I haven't had much luck in doing so for `e_visual_map` since I don't have any knowledge in javascript. I also would like to change the **hover color** from *yellow* (as you could see in the screenshot) to a different color if possible.

e_map as below:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Updated! After a lot of digging I have figured out how to add comma separators in thousand values for e_visual_map. This might not be the most sufficient and fastest way but it works and easy for me to understand!

```
data %>%
  e_charts(region) %>%
  e_map_register("NZ", nz_json) %>%
  e_map(visitors, map = "NZ") %>%
  e_visual_map(
    visitors,
    top = "20%",
    left = "0%",
    inRange = list(color = c("#3366FF","#6699FF", "#66CCFF", "#33CCFF")),
    type = "piecewise",
    splitList = list(
      list(min = 100000),
      list(min = 40000, max = 100000),
      list(min = 5000, max = 40000),
      list(value = 0)
    ),
    formatter = htmlwidgets::JS("function(value, index, values){
                if(index == 'Infinity'){
                return ' > ' + value.toLocaleString()
                }else if (value != 0){
                return value.toLocaleString() + ' - ' + index.toLocaleString()
                }else{
                return value.toLocaleString()
                }
            }")) %>%
  e_tooltip(formatter = htmlwidgets::JS("
                         function(params){
                        return('<strong>' + params.name + 
                     '</strong><br />Total: ' +  echarts.format.addCommas(params.value)) }"))
```

I still have not figured out how to change the hover color so if anyone would like to share their answers please do so.

Thanks.